# Problem parsing XML objective C code

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode4, double, nsnumber

I'm trying to develop an app that gets four coord. values from an XML file. The XML file is OK:

```
<boa1>
    <latitudine>43.10123355297304</latitudine>
    <longitudine>12.31807708740234</longitudine>
</boa1>
<boa2>
    <latitudine>43.07039260770269</latitudine>
    <longitudine>12.315673828125</longitudine>
</boa2>
```

When I parse its content trying to save the values into my class properties (NSNumber) I can only get longitudes...Why? Here's the code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"latitudine"]) {
    if (flag == FALSE) {

        NSLog(@"flag FALSE Lat1=%@",result); 
        // HERE THE RESULT IS OK
        lat1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[result doubleValue]];
        NSLog(@"Written Lat1=%@",lat1);
        // HERE THE RESULT is 0.. Why?
    } else {
        NSLog(@"flag TRUE Lat2=%@",result);
        // HERE THE RESULT IS OK
        lat2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[result doubleValue]];            }
    NSLog(@"Written lat2=%@",lat2);
    // HERE THE RESULT IS 0!
}


else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"longitudine"]) {

    if (flag == FALSE) {
        // HERE THE RESULT IS OK
        NSLog(@"flag FALSE Lon1=%@",result);
        lon1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[result doubleValue]];
        NSLog(@"written LON1=%@",lon1);
        // HERE THE RESULT IS OK
        flag = TRUE;
        // [myRegata.coordinate insertObject:lon1 atIndex:1];
    } else {

        NSLog(@"flag TRUE Lon2=%@",result);
        // HERE THE RESULT IS OK
        lon2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[result doubleValue]];
        // NSLog(@"written LON2=%@",lon2);
        // HERE THE RESULT IS OK


    }            


}}
```

Comment: What are the types of lat1 and lon1?

Comment: I tried to put the real value in lat1 like this

`if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"latitudine"]) {

            if (flag == FALSE) {
                
                NSLog(@"RESULT Lat1=%@",result);
                lat1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:43.10123355297304];
                NSLog(@"GUARDA Lat1=%@",lat1);

            }`
the log indicates that number. Don't know why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are appending also spaces\tab\n to your result string, and then numberWithDouble: fail because of that.

So use something like

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]];

    [result appendString:string];

}
```

to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You might have exceeded the limits for the floating point precision. Try using a `NSDecimalNumber` instead of `NSNumber`.

Comment: Are you using `+[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:]` when creating the `NSDecimalNumber` object??

Answer (score -1):

Here you are showing the data in NSlog like this:

```
  NSLog(@"Written Lat1=%@",lat1);
    // HERE THE RESULT is 0.. Why?

  NSLog(@"flag TRUE Lat2=%@",result);
    // HERE THE RESULT IS OK
```

So, When you using to show result it is showing correct data because XML it contains is in string format and it can be displayed using %@. But when you are showing lat1, it is not the strin so you can't show it using %@, instead of that you can use %f as it may be float or double you used.

Comment: `%@` means "an object", and `lat1` is an `NSNumber` which indeed is an object.